# What's the proper way to do automatic iterative outlier rejection?

Tags: regression, outliers, mad

I know this is a touchy subject, so I'll proceed with caution...

I am building regression models for some hundreds of thousands of data files containing only two columns. The sensor collecting these data is not great and sometimes things interfere with the measurement, so the data are extremely noisy; a typical file might contain 300 inliers and 50 outliers.

The way I'm proceeding currently is as follows:

1. Build regression model for the inliers of the data (initially all of the data)
2. Obtain residuals by subtracting the model from all of the data
3. Calculate the scale of the residuals (e.g. using STD or MAD)
4. Reject (sigma-clip) all outliers exceeding some sigma * scale
5. Repeat the process until the same outliers are rejected two iterations in a row

Sometimes the initial predictor is bad, so some of the flagged outliers are really inliers. When I check for outliers in the second iteration, I have it examine all of the data including the previously rejected outliers, and I ``unflag'' outliers if they now agree with the updated model.

The problem is that this sometimes leads to an infinite loop. If I build a model, reject a point, rebuild the model, unflag that point and reject a different point, rebuild the model, unflag that point and reject the first point again, etc., this process never ends. I could limit it so that it only iterates some predetermined number of times, but this seems like a hack to me.

So what's the right way to do it?

Comment: [IRLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares), which works in the spirit of your current procedure, often does a great job.